# A FocusNode was used after being disposed

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using TextFieldTags in my page for the tag entry. In the case of I came back from that page and again going back to that page, A FocusNode was used after being disposed.
The relevant error-causing widget was
TextFieldTags Error is coming.

I am using  textfield_tags: ^1.4.4 version.

```
child: TextFieldTags(
                                              textFieldTagsController:
                                                  _tagController,
                                              textSeparators: const [
                                                " ", //separate with space
                                                ',' //separate with comma as well
                                              ],
                                              // initialTags: tags,
                                              onTag: (tag) {
                                                //this will give tag when entered new single tag
                                                tags.add(tag);
                                              },
                                              onDelete: (tag) {
                                                //this will give single tag on delete
                                                tags.remove(tag);
                                              },
                                              validator: (tag) {
                                                //add validation for tags
                                                if (tag.length < 3) {
                                                  return "Enter tag up to 3 characters.";
                                                }
                                                return null;
                                              },

                                              tagsStyler: TagsStyler(
                                                  //styling tag style
                                                  tagTextStyle:
                                                      const TextStyle(
                                                          fontFamily:
                                                              'Chivo',
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight
                                                                  .normal),
                                                  tagDecoration:
                                                      BoxDecoration(
                                                    color: const Color(
                                                        0xFFDBE2E7),
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius
                                                            .circular(0.0),
                                                  ),
                                                  tagCancelIcon: Icon(
                                                      Icons.cancel,
                                                      size: 18.0,
                                                      color:
                                                          Colors.blue[900]),
                                                  tagPadding:
                                                      const EdgeInsets.all(
                                                          6.0)),

                                              textFieldStyler:
                                                  TextFieldStyler(
                                                //styling tag text field
                                                hintText:
                                                    "Enter Related Keywords",
                                                textFieldBorder:
                                                    const OutlineInputBorder(
                                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                      color:
                                                          Color(0xFFDBE2E7),
                                                      width: 2),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
```

Comment: Pls share your code snippet

Comment: I updated can you please check.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the dispose method and dispose your  controllers. It can be like

```dart
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tagController.dipose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: I tried not working.

Comment: can you include full sample widget that will reproduce the same error